# SecureSocial configuration issue with Play 2.1

Tags: playframework-2.1, securesocial

I want to support only facebook, twitter and google in my appliaction, so I've deleted other providers from `securesocial.conf`. My applications doesn't start right now, I'm getting following error:

```
Cannot load plugin
An exception occurred during Plugin [securesocial.core.providers.LinkedInProvider] initialization
No source available, here is the exception stack trace:
->java.lang.RuntimeException: [securesocial] Missing properties for provider 'linkedin'. Verify your configuration file is properly set.
 securesocial.core.IdentityProvider.throwMissingPropertiesException(IdentityProvider.scala:136)
 securesocial.core.OAuth1Provider.createServiceInfo(OAuth1Provider.scala:50)
 securesocial.core.OAuth1Provider.<init>(OAuth1Provider.scala:33)
 securesocial.core.providers.LinkedInProvider.<init>(LinkedInProvider.scala:29)
```

Is this a bug or I'm missing something and I've to configure SecureSocial in other way?

SecureSocial: commit [6f0ff343e1](https://github.com/jaliss/securesocial/blob/6f0ff343e1647005eedfd52e264dc1c406e05b5d), Play 2.1

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must configure `conf/play.plugins` correctly and remove unwanted providers. See also http://securesocial.ws/guide/installation.html